# Azure SDK PutBlockAsync throws error: The response ended prematurely

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net

We are trying to upload a file to the Azure Blob storage using the Azure SDK's PutBlockAsync API.

```
   using (var blockStream = new MemoryStream(block))
   {
       await blob.PutBlockAsync(blockId, blockStream, "").ContinueWith((t) => {
             if (t.IsFaulted)
             {
                SysLog.Debug($"Error occured in PutBlockAsync while uploading a block for {blob.Name}. Please check error log.");
                SysLog.Error(t.Exception);
             }
             else if (t.IsCanceled)
             {
                SysLog.Debug($"PutBlockAsync cancelled for {blob.Name}.");
             }
             else
             {                                    
                isChunkSent = true;
             }  
          });
  }
```

The upload fails with "The response ended prematurely" and the following error/trace:

```
 ---> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync(String blockId, Stream blockData, Checksum contentChecksum, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext, AggregatingProgressIncrementer progressIncrementer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Thank you for the response. I have added the code in the original post